# setSpan() on EditText deletes other spans

Tags: android, android-edittext, spannable

I have a `bold` button that, when pressed, is supposed to change the typeface of the selected text in the `EditText` `field`. This all works perfectly, with one exception. If there is `bold` typeface elsewhere in the `EditText`, and I try to create a new `bold` section, the original section is changed back to `normal`. For example, this string:

**Bold** not bold more bold.

If I highlight any of the normal words and press the button, they do become `bold`, but the first word becomes `normal`. I can't see any reason for this in my code.

Thanks!

```
final StyleSpan normalStyle = new StyleSpan(Typeface.NORMAL);
final StyleSpan boldStyle = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);
boldButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int startSelection = field.getSelectionStart();
                int endSelection = field.getSelectionEnd();
                Editable editableText = field.getText();

                StyleSpan[] selectedSpans = editableText.getSpans(startSelection, endSelection, StyleSpan.class);
                boolean isAlreadyBold = false;
                for (StyleSpan style : selectedSpans) {
                    print("The style is " + style.getStyle());
                    if (style.getStyle() == Typeface.BOLD) {
                        int styleStart = editableText.getSpanStart(style);
                        int styleEnd = editableText.getSpanEnd(style);
                        if (styleStart == startSelection && styleEnd == endSelection) {
                            editableText.removeSpan(style);
                            editableText.setSpan(normalStyle, startSelection, endSelection, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
                            isAlreadyBold = true;
                            print("Spans are equal");
                        } else if (styleStart < startSelection && styleEnd > endSelection) {
                            editableText.removeSpan(style);
                            editableText.setSpan(boldStyle, styleStart, startSelection, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                            editableText.setSpan(boldStyle, endSelection, styleEnd, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                            editableText.setSpan(normalStyle, startSelection, endSelection, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
                            isAlreadyBold = true;
                            print("Style is larger than selection");
                        } else if (styleStart < startSelection && styleEnd >= startSelection) {
                            editableText.removeSpan(style);
                            editableText.setSpan(boldStyle, styleStart, startSelection, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                            editableText.setSpan(normalStyle, startSelection, endSelection, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
                            isAlreadyBold = true;
                            print("Style begins before selection");
                        } else if (endSelection < styleEnd && endSelection >= styleStart) {
                            editableText.removeSpan(style);
                            editableText.setSpan(boldStyle, endSelection, styleEnd, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                            editableText.setSpan(normalStyle, startSelection, endSelection, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
                            isAlreadyBold = true;
                            print("Style ends after selection");
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (!isAlreadyBold) {
                    editableText.setSpan(boldStyle, startSelection, endSelection, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
                }
            }
        });
```

Note:
- `print` is a utility log that I added

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I can't see any reason for this in my code.

Create a new `StyleSpan` for each spanned area. Do not reuse `StyleSpan` instances that are already in use.

Comment: I don't see where I am reusing spans. The original first word "Bold" shouldn't be touched by this code as far as I can see. Does setting `editableText.setSpan()` delete all previous spans? If so, how do I set multiple spans, as it would delete each time?

Comment: Never mind, you're talking about the two `StyleSpan` variables at the top, yes? If I create new ones throughout this won't happen?

Comment: @Tim: "Never mind, you're talking about the two StyleSpan variables at the top, yes?" -- yes. "If I create new ones throughout this won't happen?" -- yes. "Does setting editableText.setSpan() delete all previous spans?" -- it removes any previous use of the same `CharacterStyle` (e.g., `StyleSpan`) instance. For example, in your first `else if`, you use `boldStyle` in two consecutive statements. That's not going to work.

Comment: This works, thanks! I'll accept as soon as it lets me. Thank you for explaining as well.

Comment: @Tim: Quoting [the docs for `setSpan()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html#setSpan%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int,%20int%29), with emphasis added: "Attach the specified markup object to the range start…end of the text, **or move the object to that range if it was already attached elsewhere**".